Debugging inline ASM with LLDB - treat instructions as separate statements for the step command?
In LLDB, the step command steps over a whole asm{} block as a single "statement".  Is there a way to make it treat each instruction separately so you don't have to use si to step instructions, and switch to disassembly mode to see your current position?

As a part of a course I am attending, we are writing inline asm in C. They are using Visual Studio on windows, to write and debug MSVS assembly. I wanted to get this up and running on my M2 Macbook (I can run a VM, but that is boring)
It was pretty easy to get the thing to compile. I use clang and copile like this:
clang -fasm-blocks -target x86_64-apple-macos main.c -g -O0

Here is an example code snippet:
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

uint8_t count1(uint32_t x) {
    uint8_t out;
    __asm {
        mov edx, x
        mov al, 0
next:   cmp edx, 0
        je done
        mov cl, dl
        and cl, 1
        add al, cl
        shr edx, 1
        jmp next
done:
        mov out, al
    }
    return out;
}

int main() {
    uint32_t x = 0x5789ABCD;
    uint8_t cnt = count1(x);
    printf("Number of 1s in 0x%X: %hhu\n", x, cnt);
}

The only thing that I have to do differently, is the return value. I have to move it to a C variable manually and return it. If you know how to make this work implicitly, it would be awesome, but that isn't a big deal for me.
The problem came with debugging. I use neovim and have nice debugging experience with nvim-dap and codelldb. However when I step through the code snipped above, the asm block runs in one step.
I have tried debugging with raw lldb on the cli and it does the same thing. I can step through the asm with si and di -F intel but that is a little cumbersome.
I suppose I am only missing a flag in the compilation step to generate debug symbols for the asm block. Does anyone know how to step through the __asm block within LLDB and consequently neovim? Is my understanding of the problem correct?

The only thing that I have to do differently, is the return value. - Correct, it seems that MSVC inline asm actually defines the behaviour of leaving a value in EAX and falling off the end of a non-void function.  I think I've seen it respect those semantics even when inlining a function containing an asm{} block. But clang -fasm-blocks definitely does not respect that, probably not even clang-cl is compatible with such code. Clang treats it as undefined behaviour when a caller uses the return value of a function that doesn't return one (in C; in C++ it's UB even to fall off the end)

MSVC-style asm{} blocks are necessarily inefficient, forcing inputs to be in memory not registers.  MSVC itself lets you avoid bouncing one output (a return value) through memory with that hack you mention, clang doesn't. But if you care about efficiency, clang also supports GNU C inline asm, where you tell the compiler about your inputs and outputs with constraints, and can even let it pick registers that are convenient for the context where it's inlining your function. 'asm', '__asm' and '__asm__'? / https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info

Thanks for the info, I found some of this while researching my problem. I don't really care about efficiency at this point. I am pretty much looking for a similar setup as the course organizers have (MSVS). I think I have something pretty good, except the debuging part. I wasn't able to find a debuggingl debuging solution that would step through the instructions in the __asm block one-by-one

Yeah, understood.  My point was mostly that support for -fasm-blocks is mostly for compatibility with MSVC, not intended as the main way for people to write inline asm with Clang.  From the compat perspective, it would be more compatible to support the fall-off-the-end hack, but that would probably be hard for the compiler internals.  And in terms of generating debug info or whatever it would take (putting statement-break debug metadata for each asm line?) that might be why it was a low priority, since GNU C inline asm is also a single statement for the whole asm().

I wouldn't be surprised if -fasm-blocks works internally by translating it to an Extended Asm statement with clobbers and memory input / output operands, like asm("..." : "=m"(out) : "m"(x) : "rax", "rcx", "rdx"); for your case.  That would explain the lack of single-step points within the asm block.

I can see why it might be impossible, but if Visual Studio can do it, I don't see a reason why clang couldn't. Maybe they handle inline ASM differently, and their way enables this while clang's doesnt?

Yes, different compilers can make different debug info, and that would be the obvious explanation for this.  No reason (at least in theory) why Clang couldn't in future be patched to make separate single-step points inside an asm statement, but it might be a major change to the internals and a lot of new code if my guess is right about how it's currently implemented  Asm blocks were MSVC's native style of inline asm, vs. being a late addition to Clang.

Maybe you can force it.  Does clang have the equivalent of the #line or .loc directives?  Alternately, what about this (from codelldb)?  This is supposed to allow you to "perform instruction-level stepping rather than source-level stepping."

@DavidWohlferd I experimented with you suggestion and it is possible! I am able to insert .loc directives into the asm and it will work! I attempted to make a Clang plugin that will do it automatically, but I hit a segfault on Rewriter.getRangeSize(..) and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong... https://github.com/Hackder/asm_debug

Glad it's working for you.  Sorry, can't help with the plugin.  Beyond my knowledge.  Still, you shouldn't need to debug this asm code every day.  Manually updating the .loc as needed seems tedious, but workable.

So, I found a solution. As it turns out, you can specify the locations manually. This is how that would look:
uint8_t count1(uint32_t x) {
    int out;
    __asm {
        .file 1 "main.c"
        .loc 1 9
        mov edx, [x]
        .loc 1 11
        mov al, 0
        .loc 1 13
next:   cmp edx, 0
        .loc 1 15
        je done
        .loc 1 17
        mov cl, dl
        .loc 1 19
        and cl, 1
        .loc 1 21
        add al, cl
        .loc 1 23
        shr edx, 1
        .loc 1 25
        jmp next
done:
        .loc 1 28
        mov out, al
    }
    return out;
}

Doing this manually would be very annoying, and modifying the source code would mess up how the source looks in the debugger (you would see the .loc ... declarations)
What we can do, is use clang to compile the c file into the intermediate LLVM IR, modify that, either with a custom compiler pass or with a simple script (I chose the script), and then compile the IR into an executable:
clang -S -emit-llvm -o main.ll main.c -fasm-blocks -target x86_64-apple-macos -g -O0
python3 preprocess.py main.ll
clang main.ll -o a.out -fasm-blocks -target x86_64-apple-macos -g -O0

This creates an executable with all the debug symbols and the original source code, which is what I was after in the first place.
Here is the python script for anyone interested:
import sys

current_file_no = 0


def get_file_no():
    global current_file_no
    current_file_no += 1
    return current_file_no


def process_asm(asm_string: str, source_filename: str, first_line: int) -> str:
    instructions = asm_string.split("\\0A\\09")

    file_no = get_file_no()
    result = [f".file {file_no} \\22{source_filename}\\22"]

    loc_directives = [
        f".loc 1 {line}" for line in range(first_line, first_line + len(instructions))
    ]
    for loc, inst in zip(loc_directives, instructions):
        result.append(loc)
        result.append(inst)

    return "\\0A\\09".join(result)


asm_prefix = "call void asm sideeffect inteldialect "


def main():
    filename = sys.argv[1]

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    source_filename = None

    result = []
    for line in lines:
        stripped_line = line.strip()

        if stripped_line.startswith("source_filename"):
            source_filename = stripped_line.split('"')[1]
            result.append(line)
            continue

        if stripped_line.startswith("call void asm sideeffect inteldialect "):
            start = line.find(asm_prefix) + len(asm_prefix) + 1
            end = start
            while line[end] != '"':
                end += 1
            asm_string = line[start:end]

            dbg_entry = line.split("!dbg ")[1].split(",")[0]
            di_location = [ln for ln in lines if ln.startswith(dbg_entry)][0]
            line_number = int(di_location.split("line: ")[1].split(",")[0])

            assert source_filename is not None
            new_asm = process_asm(asm_string, source_filename, line_number + 1)
            result.append(line[:start] + new_asm + line[end:])
            continue

        result.append(line)

    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write("".join(result))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

